# how to generate embed codes for integrating chatbots to other web application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, botframework, dialogflow-es

I build a chatbot tool using django application where by clicking in some functions it will generate some intents and entities.

Now I want to build a chat box where these requests and response comes from the tool and also integrate the chatbot to other webapps.

For example in api.ai or bot framework, once intents and entities are created then we can use embed code(like: `src="https://bot.api.ai/<uuid>`" or `https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/sample_questions?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'`))

How do I get those codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the HTML embed code for your bot's WebChat component, log into the Bot Portal at https://dev.botframework.com - then navigate to your bot in the "My bots" section.  Click on the "Channels" menu in the upper right, and click the "Edit" link to the right of the WebChat channel.
[image]

In the WebChat channel configuration page, click the "plus" icon to add a new site definition.  After you have added your site, it will show the HTML embed code as well as the keys used for this WebChat instance.
[image]

Comment: thank you Nils W.. but my question is how I can also generate embed code from my django web app?? as like bot framework embed code generation